# How to get two different colors of Arabic letters and fatah?

Tags: xetex, polyglossia, arabtex

**Question:** How to get  two different colors of Arabic letters and fatah?
MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}

\setmainfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}
\begin{document}
\Huge
\textarab{ba}
\textarab{a}
\end{document}
```

Output:
[image]
I want to get :
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can print the fatah/fatha as a separate character in a different color. However, this means that the normal positioning mechanisms of the character do not work anymore, as the fatha does not know to which character it is attached. This means that you need to do manual tweaking to get the positioning right.

In the code below a command `\clrfatha` is defined that allows for horizontal positioning and optionally also for vertical positioning.

You can enter characters as Unicode characters, as `arabxetex` commands, or as Unicode codepoints (for example from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arabic_script_in_Unicode).

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[voc]{arabxetex}

\setmainfont{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic,Scale=1.1]{Amiri}

\newcommand{\clrfatha}[3][0pt]{%
\arabicfont%
\hskip#2\raisebox{#1}{\textcolor{blue}{\char"064E}}\hskip-#2%
\textcolor{purple}{#3}%
}

\begin{document}
\Huge
\textarab{ba}
\textarab{a}
\clrfatha[-8pt]{6pt}{ب}
\clrfatha{-5pt}{ا}
\clrfatha[-8pt]{6pt}{\textarab{b}}
\clrfatha{-5pt}{\char"0627} % unicode codepoint
\textarab{ba}
\textarab{a}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]